# Argotic Syndication Framework

Tags: rss, feed, argotic

Does anyone know of any tutorials for this framework?
Whats the opinion on the use of this for extracting data from an RSS Feed?
Good or bad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to consider using the System.ServiceModel.Syndication namespace. Inside, you'll find a class called SyndicationFeed with a static method Load that might do everything you need.

I already posted this for another question, but it may be helpful for you too:

**System.ServiceModel.Sydication**

- is about 9 times faster than Argotic
- does not have rdf support
- doesn't have support for atom versions < 1
- doesn't have support for rss versions < 1
- fails with XmlException on about 30% of the feeds I give in "from the wild" (this is the deal-breaker for me)

**Argotic**

- hasn't been updated since Jul 2 2008
- is slow (see above)
- has very good support for all types of feeds: all version of atom, rss, rdf (as far as I can tell)
- is slightly harder to use than System.ServiceModel.Sydication; you need to determine what kind of feed you have before letting Argotic parse it, and then you need custom logic to deal with each of 3 different classes depending on the type of feed. In other words, you need to wrap Argotic before it's useful.

Comment: There is a GenericFeed class in Argotic that can be used to consume a feed without knowing its format ahead of time. It also supports most of the common feed extensions is use in the wild. I haven't had much time to work on it, but I am glad you made me aware of the speed/performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

The many links on the [CodePlex wiki](http://argotic.codeplex.com/) lead to a number of tutorials. Also, check out [DimeCasts.net](http://www.dimecasts.net/casts/castdetails/19). Derik Whittaker also has a simple sample [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/06/10/generate-your-own-rss-feed-with-argotic.aspx).